# Is there a way to treat script parameter as stored parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch

To the documents that have been stored in ES, I would like to add script parameters that could be potentially used for filtering and/or sorting with other stored parameters. These fields have to be calculated on every query.

Say the original document has the fields name, validFrom, validTo and by using validFrom and validTo, the status field has to be calculated (if current time is between validFrom and validTo, the status is 'active'; if the current time is greater than 'validTo', the status is 'expired').
So no matter the filter and sorting criteria, the returned documents should contain the fields name, validFrom, validTo, and status.

For this purpose, I have written the following script:

```
"script_fields": {
    "status": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        long now = new Date().getTime(); 
        long validToLong = doc["validTo"].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); 
        long timeDiff = validToLong - now; 
        String status = timeDiff > 0 ? "VALID" : "EXPIRED"; 
        status
        """
      }
    }
  }
```

In some cases, it is required to retrieve just the valid documents. In this case, I would like to know if there is a way to somehow refer to the written script instead of nesting the script into query statement and write the query in the manner

```
"query": {
    "match": {
            "status": "VALID"
        }
  }
```

Also, in some cases, the status value could be used for sorting and in this case I would like to use the script above.

Basically, somehow, I would like to script field status, in this case, to emulate the stored parameter properties. Is there a way to do that or is there any other way to automatically execute the certain script to calculate arbitrary parameters on every query and use these values for filtering/sorting along with other stored parameters in certain cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store that script and then refer to it in either script fields, script filter or sort.

First store the script. You'll note that I'm checking if params are present or not, this is to be able to use the same script in multiple contexts, you'll see how it works in an instant

```
POST _scripts/validity
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
        long now = new Date().getTime(); 
        long validToLong = doc["validTo"].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); 
        long timeDiff = validToLong - now; 
        return params.size() > 0 ? (timeDiff > 0 ? params.valid : params.invalid) : (timeDiff > 0);
"""
  }
}
```

Now you can issue your query with `script_fields` and a `filter` where both use the exact same script and produce the result you want:

```
POST valids/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "status": {
      "script": {
        "id": "validity",
        "params": {
          "valid": "VALID",
          "invalid": "INVALID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": {
        "id": "validity"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results: As you can see only the valid documents come back.

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "valids",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "_m6Ck24BJvP7VWZfnCC4",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "fields" : {
      "status" : [
        "VALID"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "valids",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "_26Ck24BJvP7VWZftyCR",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "fields" : {
      "status" : [
        "VALID"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

If you add the script query in a `bool/must_not` query, then only the INVALID ones will come back.

Comment: I tried to modify the script in order to return statuses active=1, expired=2, notActiveYet=3, deleted=4. In case of using query, I get an error: class_cast_exception: Cannot cast from [int] to [boolean].

Comment: The query needs to return a boolean value in order to know if the document matches the script filter or not (in a filter context a script can only answer yes or no). Or are you talking about the use of the script in the `script_fields` context?